# Lag between publication of question and posting on front page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have noticed that there is a lag between the time a question is added to the site and the time it appears on the main page. It is usually only a couple of seconds, but it may be as long as a few minutes? Anybody know why this is?

Comment: You can find a nearly realtime list in the active tab under questions http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active

Comment: Oh it's a caching thing. There's got to be a good post on meta.stackoverflow.com about it. Lemme look.

Comment: Oy I can't find a good post on the topic. But I'm sure that's the answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA Oh that makes sense. It's too bad that we only notice caching when it's not what we want.

Comment: Similar: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2039

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical answer is always: caching.

That said, we *have* implemented a [live update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) feature for various and sundry pages on the site. The homepage, however, is still subject to a degree of caching.

We're gradually moving towards more and more live updating on our sites. It used to take several minutes to have a new question appear. Now, it takes several seconds. That's pretty good by my estimation!